# Android won't stop GPS intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle, android-pendingintent, android-location

I want to ask for the GPS location, even when the app is in the background. Therefore I used a PendingIntent as follows:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class);
mLocationIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mLocationIntent);
```

It works great. However, the GPS location is still updating, even when the MainActivity is destroyed. The Intent Service won't stop. I tried to stop the Intent in the onDestroyed method of the MainActivity like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationIntent);
}
```

...but this method won't get called.

How can I stop the Intent when the MainActivity is destroyed?

Comment: Android can kill your app at any time if it is in the background. It can kill the app without calling `onDestroy()` on any activities. You will need to come up with a different architecture for your application. Why do you want GPS locations when your app is in the background if you want to stop the GPS locations when your app is destroyed? For Android, having an app in the background isn't significantly different from having the app killed.

Comment: I want to evaluate the GPS location to know when the user has reached a specific location. Then I want to send the result to an Android Wear device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it this way you will need to provide the user a way to turn this on and off.

If you register for GPS updates using a `PendingIntent`, this means that your app will get the GPS updates even when it is not running. This is what this is designed for. Even the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) is pretty clear about this:

> This method is suited for the background use cases, more specifically
>   for receiving location updates, even when the app has been killed by
>   the system.

If you only want to get GPS updates while your app is running, then you should use one of the other `requestLocationUpdates()` variants that use a callback or a listener. These variants will stop getting updates if your app is killed.

Comment: I think you got my problem right. Then this is simply an Android limitation I got here. It requires me in my case to listen for GPS positions in the background, even when the app is not running anymore. 

I cannot use the LocationListener implementation because the GPS updates will stop, when the user switches to another app or has the app in the background. Otherwise I would like to use it. I don't like that it's not possible to stop a background service when the main app is destroyed since it has some costs like battery usage etc...

Comment: No, that isn't true. If you switch to using a listener, you will still get updates even if the user switches to another app. Your app will go to the background, but it will still be alive. The problem is that Android can kill background processes at any time, so you have little control over how long it will stay alive.

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work with a listener. As soon as I had the app in the background, the listener stopped to be working.

Comment: JFMG - did you try running your locationlistener on a service instead of an activity? that is what I do and it runs fine without stopping.

Answer (score 2):

When you press the home button or the back button of your device, the 'ondestroy()' method will not get called immediately. According to android's documentation, thisis **The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space...**. A suggestion will be to stop the GPS update instead in the 'onPause()' method. Something like this :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationIntent);
}
```

Comment: OP wants the GPS update to continue when the app is in the background. That pretty much disqualifies your answer, since `onPause()` will be called before the app goes to the background.

Comment: @DavidWasser you are right.
I want that the background service is able to communicate with an Android Wear device so I know when the user is reaching a specific location. Smartphone users tend to use other apps while they are going somewhere, so I need to ask for the location in a background service. Switching to another app will call onPause(), however I am interested in when the app is destroyed.

If that is not possible I am forced to ask for the GPS location as long as the background service exists...